# Why do I get a different sum and errors for addition in Java

Tags: java

I am really new to Java. I have a question regarding the numbers. I was given a task of printing 2 numbers side by side.

For example, if there are 2 numbers: `a = 5`, `b = 9`, I should print both of them side by side. So the output would look `59`.

In python, we can do:

```
print(a,b)
```

Even though it adds a space, I can remove that later.

But in Java. when I do `System.out.println(a,b)`, I get:

```
error: no suitable method found for println(int,int)
        System.out.println(a,b);
                  ^
```

So after scratching my head for a little bit, I came up with `System.out.println(a+''+b)`
And then it gives:

```
error: empty character literal
        System.out.println(a+''+b);
                             ^
```

So, looking at the error, it looked like `''` is invalid. So I did `' '`
And the result I got was:

```
46
```

Why did I get an error?
When I do:

```
System.out.println(a+""+b);
```

It prints what I want: `59`

Here is my code (working):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=5;
        int b=6;
        System.out.println(a+""+b);
    }
}
```

I just want to know why does this above work while doing `' '` doesn't. It is related to the data type?

Comment: Java is not Python. You should read a bit about the basics and syntax of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`' '` is a `char`. It will be autocasted to an `int` (the [ASCII code](https://www.asciitable.com/) of `blank` is used, it has the value `32`). Then the addition is executed (`5 + 32 + 9`, which will evaluate to `46`). That explain why we see the `46` being printed out.

Replacing `' '` with `""` will force the `int`-values being autocasted to `String`s, which will then work as expected.

Another possible solution woudl be to use [`System.out.printf("%d%d%n", a, b);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)).

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ab1ZIh)

Answer (score 1):

The single quote `' '` is a space character, and printing `5 + ' ' + 9` results in adding the integers with its [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value which is 32 (5 + 32 + 9 = 46).

You can either use `""` or `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("%d%d", 5, 9);
```

Comment: No problem :) my comments will self-destruct shortly

Answer (score 0):

for `''` it represents a char value, so it recognizes as ASCII value(32).that's why it gives you a different output `(5 + 32 + 9)` . By using `""`, `int` will auto-cast into a string

example :

```
1+2+""+4 =34
```